# How to override nth-child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Lets assume I have this simplified HTML tree:

```
 <ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>         
   <li>Item 3</li>
    .
    .
    .
   <li>Item n</li>
 </ul>
```

And this CSS style:

```
ul li:nth-child(2n){ background-color: blue; }
```

I have no access to this selector, and so I want to override it to be

```
ul li:nth-child(3n){ background-color: red; }
```

However, this affects **both every 2nd, as well as every 3rd element**.
Here's a [js-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/opherv/ymyqx/) example.

How can I override an nth-child psuedoselector with a new formula, so that only my new formula (3n) takes effect?

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't match your code. It's also not clear what you're looking for. What do you mean by override? I can see that the red is overriding the blue just fine.

Comment: Reset the 3n rule with background: none; or transparent;.  Then do your 2n rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ul li:nth-child(3n){ background-color: transparent; }
ul li:nth-child(2n){ background-color: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want.

```
ul li:nth-child(3n+1){
    background-color: white;
}

ul li:nth-child(3n+2){
    background-color: blue;
}

ul li:nth-child(3n){
    background-color: red;
}
```